# Об особенностях СПП с придаточным времени при наличии местоимения "тогда"

Tags: грамматика, союзы, спп, союзные-слова

Как сделать синтаксический разбор предложения при наличии местоимения ***тогда***?

Какой это **вид** придаточного? Слово ***когда*** в этом случае союз или союзное слово?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152214/discussion-on-question-by-sharon--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

1. По семантике этот вид предложений относят к СПП с придаточным **времени.** Такой разбор предлагается в школе. Но и там [Литневская](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p92_TOC_idp1662135232) делает **особое замечание:**

*При наличии в главной части слова со значением времени, в том числе указательного слова **тогда**, придаточная присоединяется **союзным словом когда,** стоит после этого слова в главной части и относится именно к нему.*

Это надо учитывать при разборе.

2. По грамматике  это **местоименно-определительное** (местоименно-соотносительное) придаточное, местоименная пара ***тогда — когда.*** Такое противоречие создает ситуацию неразличения вида связи для слова ***когда***, так как в некоторых случаях местоимение *тогда* можно опустить.

В то же время это возможно не всегда. Местоименная природа слова ***когда*** подчеркивается в таких предложениях: *Встреча может произойти ***там и тогда***, ***где и когда*** для этого возникнут условия.*

Материал взят **из учебника Кустовой** "Синтаксис современного русского языка. Курс лекций. 2013 год.

**Примечание.** Важно отметить, что наличие слова ***тогда*** изменяет не только вид придаточного, но и его категорию. СПП  делятся на два типа: **нерасчлененной структуры** (обычно местоименная связь) и **расчлененной** структуры (обычно союзная связь).